# is Selenium Remote Webdriver Server similar to Hudson CI?

Tags: selenium, grid, webdriver, selenium-grid

Right now I am using Hudson CI to launch browser in xvnc and run my tests through Webdriver (pre 2.0)

Should I use Selenium remote webdriver instead? is that more efficient than hudson ci?

I want to run my tests on Amazon....are there any selenium remote webdriver server or Selenium Grid plugin that can already integrate with Amazon? Should I pursue Grid or remotedriver server?

My ultimate goal is to be able to launch multiple tests parallel on Selenium on Amazon and be able to quickly scale up and down.

Right now I pay $100/month for server that has hudson CI on it....but I never end up using the whole capacity....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid or the Remote Server does not replace a CI tool like Hudson. They will not schedule jobs, parallelize your tests, report results (with history) or send email/IM notifications when builds fail.

So you would still have Hudson (or similar) for all those things, possibly using Grid or the Remote Server to decouple the machine(s) running the browser(s) from the one running the tests.

Comment: I was just worried that I might be trying to reinvent wheel or that hudson might consume more resources than Grid or Remote Server.  Right now, I am really loving hudson exactly for the reasons you mentioned (scheduling of jobs, report of result, email/im notifications)....

Answer (score 1):

Selenium Grid will allow you launch multiple tests in parallel. And with the right configuration you can even run the tests of different browsers in parallel.

Selenium grid is still using selenium 1.x remote control drivers. So if you already have your tests written in webdriver code, then you might not be able to use it with current Selenium grid. There is a new version of selenium grid - Grid 2.0 that will be out soon. That will be support webdriver as well.

Comment: Has there been any mention of the release date of Grid 2.0 ?

Comment: it will be included in selenium2 beta 4 which will probably be released in a couple of weeks. If you can't wait you can download and build the source right now.

Comment: Oh that is great news! I think I will wait for this new release.

Comment: :) Yes Sir, Grid 2.0 has been released few days back. Do try it out. :) http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/selenium-2-0rc2-the-better-working-release/